# Prepared statements in PHP

Tags: beginner, php, security, sql-injection

I just heard of prepared statement in PHP and decided to prevent SQL injection with it and wrote a script testing it.

I would like to know what security threats this script can prevent, what security threats this script is vulnerable to, and how these threats are blocked.

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userMsgField']) && !empty($_POST['userMsgField']) || isset($_POST['hash']) && !empty($_POST['hash']))
{
$my_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];
$rep_msg = $_POST['userMsgField'];
$hash = $_SESSION['hash'];
$flag = 0;

$sql =<<<EOF
SELECT * FROM connect WHERE (user_one = '$my_id' AND hash = '$hash') OR (user_two = '$my_id' AND hash = '$hash');
EOF;

$ret = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $user_one = $row['user_one'];
    $user_two = $row['user_two'];

    if ($user_one == $my_id)
    {
        $to_id = $user_two;
    }
    else
    {
        $to_id = $user_one;
    }


    $isql =<<<EOF
    INSERT INTO messager (message, group_hash, from_id, flag, to_id) VALUES (:message, :group_hash, :from_id, :flag, :to_id);
EOF;
    $bsql =<<<EOF
    INSERT INTO chatportal (message, group_hash, from_id, flag, to_id) 
VALUES (:message, :group_hash, :from_id, :flag, :to_id);
EOF;

    $stmt = $db->prepare($isql);
    $bstmt = $db->prepare($bsql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':message', $rep_msg, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':group_hash', $hash, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $stmt->bindValue(':from_id', $my_id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $stmt->bindValue(':flag', $flag, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $stmt->bindValue(':to_id', $to_id, SQLITE3_TEXT);

    $bstmt->bindValue(':message', $rep_msg, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':group_hash', $hash, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':from_id', $my_id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':flag', $flag, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $bstmt->bindValue(':to_id', $to_id, SQLITE3_TEXT);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $bresult = $bstmt->execute();

    if ($reuslt && $bresult)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please first convert the first SQL statement to a prepared statement. And fix the typo in a variable name.

Comment: You should read about [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you don't know what SQL injection  is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-review answers

1. what security threats this script can prevent - sql injection
2. what security threats this script is vulnerable to - sql injection
3. how these threats are blocked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks

Review answer.

Your code is bloated with unnecessary operators, such as heredoc. 
It is also recommended to use **PDO** instead of sqlite, as it will let you to use array binding, which is especially useful in this case as you are inserting equal sets of data.

**Besides, you should use prepared statements for your database interactions.**

There are also other improvements and fixes.

```
if (!empty($_POST['userMsgField']) && !empty($_POST['hash']))
{
    $my_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];
    $rep_msg = $_POST['userMsgField'];
    $hash = $_POST['hash'];
    $flag = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM connect WHERE (user_one = ? AND hash = ?) 
                                     OR (user_two = ? AND hash = ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$my_id,$hash,$my_id,$hash]);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $user_one = $row['user_one'];
        $user_two = $row['user_two'];

        $to_id = ($user_one == $my_id) ? $user_two : $user_one;

        $data = [
            'message' => $rep_msg,
            'group_hash' => $hash,
            'from_id' => $my_id,
            'flag' => $flag,
            'to_id' => $to_id,
        ];

        $sql ="INSERT INTO messager (message, group_hash, from_id, flag, to_id) 
                            VALUES (:message,:group_hash,:from_id,:flag,:to_id)";
        $db->prepare($sql)->execute($data);

        $sql ="INSERT INTO chatportal (message, group_hash, from_id, flag, to_id)
                              VALUES (:message,:group_hash,:from_id,:flag,:to_id)";
        $db->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
    }
}
```

Now this code is much cleaner and easier to read. And safe, of course.